# what is Bary-centric coordinates?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Note : Im new to the homology theory

I have some confusion in  Bredon  Topology and Geometry book Page no :  $169$

> $1.1$ Definition  . Let  $\mathbb{R^{\infty}}$  have  the  standard basis $e_0,e_1,......$Then the standard $p-$ simplex  is $Δ_p= \{x =\sum_{i=0}^{p} \lambda_ie_i | \sum\lambda_i=1 , 0 \le \lambda_i \le 1\}$. The  $\lambda$  are called   bary-centric coordinates

**My confusion** : Im not getting  why $\sum\lambda_i=1?$

**My thinking** :  Take $p=2$,then $Δ_2$  is a  triangle.See the diagram given below

[image]

From the diagram we have  $x= \lambda_1$,  $y= \lambda_2$ and   $z= \lambda_3$

But  here $x=y=z=1$

$\implies \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3= x+y+z=1+1+1=3 \neq 1$

This leads to a contradiction  $\sum\lambda_i=1$

Comment: That's not what $x$ means in the definition.

Comment: That's also not what the $\lambda_i$ mean, either.

Comment: @Randall i think here $x= Ax +by +cz$

Comment: How does that make sense?  The idea is that any point in the triangle can be written as $\lambda_1A + \lambda_2B + \lambda_3C$.

Comment: The problem is here "From the diagram we have $x=\lambda_1$, $y=\lambda_2$ and $z=\lambda_3$". What made you think that the lambdas are the lengths of the sides of the triangle?

Comment: @jjagmath Actually,   I misunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/In-three-dimensions-the-simplex-is-a-two-dimensional-triangle-whose-vertices-are-the_fig3_232659411) are [three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#/media/File:2D-simplex.svg) [places](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39785/46581) you can see pictures of the $2$-simplex as a subset of $\Bbb R^3$. Hopefully that can help you interpret the given definition.